# Proof verification: $\mathbb{E}[X] = \int_0^\infty P(X > \alpha) d\alpha$

Tags: probability, integration, solution-verification, expected-value

I want to show that given a probabilty density $P: \mathbb R^+ \rightarrow [0, 1]$, its expectation obeys the identity: $\mathbb{E}[X] = \int_0^\infty P(X > \alpha) d\alpha$.

- We assume that the density $P$ is defined on $[0, u]$. We will get the final version by setting $u \rightarrow \infty$ **(nit 1)**
- Begin by defining the cumulative density $C(x) = \int_0^x P(\alpha) d\alpha$.
- $C'(x) = P(x) - P(0)$ from fundamental theorem of calculus. We need to assume that $P(0) = 0$ so that $C'(x) = P(x)$.  **(nit 2)**.
- This gives us $dC(x) = P(x)$.

Now compute expectation:
\begin{align*}
&\mathbb E[X] = \int_0^u xP(x)dx  \quad [UdV]\\
&\left[ \text{use product rule: }\int U dV = UV - \int V dU \right] \\
&= [xC(x)]_0^u - \int_0^u C(x) \cdot 1 dx \\
&= uC(u) -  \int_0^u C(x)dx \\
&\text{[$C(u) = 1$ since $u$ was upper bound of distribution]} \\
&= u - \int_{0}^uC(x) dx \\
&= \int_0^u 1 dx  - \int_{0}^uC(x) dx \\
&= \int_0^u [1 - C(x)] dx \\
&= \int_0^u [1 - P(X \leq x)] dx \\
&= \int_0^u P(X > x) dx \\
\blacksquare
\end{align*}

Set $u \rightarrow \infty$ to get the final desired expression.

Is this proof watertight? I'm nervous about (i) first proving it for finite $u$ and then setting the limit; (ii) The assumption that $P(0) = 0$. I believe (i) is all right since that's the definition of integral with limit infinity. As for (ii), I believe this is also okay since we are assuming something about the distribution over a set of measure zero (a single point $0$). Still, I'm nervous, so a proof verification would be very appreicated.

Comment: **If** the probability density fct is continuous, the cumulated probability fct vanishes if we consider only a single point. Without stating this assumption, you probably assume it. Therefore, the $P(0)=0$ is fine, because the density fct must be finite.

Comment: Using the notation $P$ to mean both the underlying probability measure and the density of $X$ is confusing and should be avoided.

Comment: If you restrict $P$ on $[0,u]$, $P$ is not a density anymore, and $C(u) \neq 1$

Comment: Perhaps I stated this incorrectly. What I mean is that $P$ on has support on $[0, u]$. We then recover the original statement by setting $u \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: this is false $\mathbb E[X] = \int_0^u xP(x)dx$ if $u\neq \infty $

Comment: @Masacroso Can you provide an example? I claim that if $u$ is the largest value in $support(P(x))$, then $\mathbb{E}[X] = \int_0^u P(x) dx$. Was this unclear from the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix your proof just noticing that

$$
\int_{0}^\infty tf_X(t) \mathop{}\!d t=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^n tf_X(t) \mathop{}\!d t
$$

from the monotone convergence theorem. Hence, following your work, you get that

$$
\mathrm{E}[X]=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{0}^n(F_X(n)-F_X(t))\mathop{}\!d t=\int_{0}^\infty (1-F_X(t))\mathop{}\!d t 
$$

where we had used again the monotone convergence theorem as $\mathbf{1}_{[0,n]}(t)(F_X(n)-F_X(t))$ increases to $1-F_X(t)$ as $n\to\infty $.

Comment: Can you please expand your answer to tell me where the proof is _wrong_? I don't precisely understand what step of the proof is incorrect.

Comment: @SiddharthBhat you cannot assume that the domain of $f_X$ is $[0,u]$ as you did

Comment: So the resolution is to assume the domain is $\lim_{u \rightarrow \infty} [0, u]$?

Comment: @SiddharthBhat the domain is $[0,\infty )$, it is not a limit, a domain is a set. We only had used the monotone convergence theorem twice. Im assuming you knows a bit of measure theory, the first identity in my answer can also be rewritten as $$\int_{[0,\infty )}tf_X(t) \mathop{}\!d t=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{[0,\infty )}\mathbf{1}_{[0,n]}(t)t f_X(t) \mathop{}\!d t$$ Thus we are exploiting the fact that $\mathbf{1}_{[0,n]}(t)t f_X(t)$ increases to $tf_X(t)$ (as $n\to \infty $)

Comment: I sadly do not know measure theory, so I don't really understand what is broken in my proof, and how this fixes it. My understanding is that I had $\int_[0, u) xP(x)$ which will not necessarily be equal to $\mathbb{E[}X]$. So, I have to evaluate $\int_[0, \infty] x P(x) dx$. Do do this, I need to use dominated convergence?

Comment: @SiddharthBhat I dont know how to put the dominated convergence theorem here, because to use it you almost need to use the fact that you want to prove prior to be proved. It is very strange that you knows the dominated convergence theorem and you dont knows measure theory. In any case in this exercise you can use the improper integral of Riemann instead of the Lebesgue integral if you wish, both coincide and are equal, so where I had put $\int_{[0,\infty )}$ in my previous comment you can put $\int_0 ^\infty $ and assume that the integral is an improper integral of Riemann